# Mapbox iOS: How get camera for geometry/equivalent for Android getCameraForGeometry

Tags: ios, camera, geometry, mapbox

I am trying to center the map on certain Feature from FeatureCollection. Within Mapbox Android SDK there is method on MapboxMap called getCameraForGeometry, where I can pass the Geometry of the Feature and get desired map position.

How can I do the same for iOS version of Mapbox SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`[MGLMapView camera:fittingShape:edgePadding:]`](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/5.4.0/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(im)camera:fittingShape:edgePadding:) or [`[MGLMapView cameraThatFitsShape:direction:edgePadding:`](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/5.4.0/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(im)cameraThatFitsShape:direction:edgePadding:) to change the camera to include a specific shape or feature.

If you have annotations that you would like to show, you can also use [`[MGLMapView showAnnotations:animated:]`](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/5.4.0/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(im)showAnnotations:animated:) or one of the related methods.